# Loop the times of the length of a shorter list in each iteration

Tags: python

```
nv_sides = [[1, 0], [0, 1], [-1, 0], [0, -1]]

for nv in range(len(nv_sides)):
    if nv_sides[nv][0] > x or nv_sides[nv][1] > x:
        del nv_sides[nv]

    if nv_sides[nv][0] > y or nv_sides[nv][1] > y:
        del nv_sides[nv]

    if nv_sides[nv][0] < 0 or nv_sides[nv][1] < 0:
        del nv_sides[nv]
```

As you can see, the *nv_sides* list gets shorter in each iteration so at the 4th iteration I get an index  out of range error.

How can I solve that?

Comment: use a while loop and create a variable that store the length of the list

Comment: The best way is simply to create a new list and append to it in the loop.

Comment: Deleting as you go invalidates the index (nv) at each iteration.  However, if you do this in reverse order, the items you delete will always be at greater indexes than the ones that you still have to process.  use `for nv in reversed(range(len(nv_sides))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick is to run the `for` loop from the end to the beginning. That way, as elements are deleted you will still be working toward elements that are still there.

```
for nv in range(len(nv_sides) -1, -1, -1):
```